# use y_pred from another model in keras custom loss function

Tags: keras

I am have two model with similar input and output shape
I want to train model1 with loss fuction witch take its y_pred from model2 prediction.

```
model1 
model2

def myloss(y_pred, y_true):
  y_pred = model2.predict()

model1.compile(loss=myloss)
```

Is ther way to do it with keras?